# Apache CouchDB Replication

Tags: apache, couchdb, database-replication

Why would a new target replica of a CouchDB database be over twice the size in the filesystem as the source database after the replication is finished? I have a CouchDB database that has 2.5 million documents, and takes up about 597MB on the filesystem. When I replicate to another database on the same system, the size of the replica is 1.4GB. I have deleted and recreated both the source and target databases from scratch, and populated the source. So the replica is totally new, and doesn't have any other data in it.

Comment: What happens after you run a compaction on the target replica?

Comment: Do you have compressible attachments? If you do, is compression level of source and dest DBs equal?